# Dynamic CSS using custom http handler issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have implemented Dynamic CSS using custom http handler.
With this,i am giving an option for the user to choose their own CSS/color scheme.

Everything works fine.But when user A logs in,his color scheme loads up but after session time is out,the css color scheme is going back to default color scheme.

Any help would be highly appreciated
-JB

Comment: Why not store the information about which css to use in a cookie rather than the session?

Comment: I am not using session to store css.its the single css file, i have just used variables,which gets replaced with the user specific colors(stored in db).

Answer (score 0):

*Session variable destroy as the session ends like on click of logout button*.

So if you want to save the preference of user either you can save this in a *cookie* or you can save it in a *database* as a user preference style.

If you saved this setting in a database then you can always be able to display the user preference style anytime and anywhere.

Comment: Problem is...When a user A is logged in and kept idle for some time,later when he clicks on any controls,style is going off.but the functionality remains same.

Comment: that is what I am saying. When Idle for sometime, it may possible that his/her session has lost along with that session variable which holds the value of (which style should used). So either you can use cookie or database to save this variable.